# Bash Script To Add Date Threshold to S3 `cp` function

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to be able to `aws S3 cp` with a date threshold, but it doesn't have a switch for that functionality.

So, I would like to write a Bash script for it. Calling `aws s3 ls` with the `--recursive` switch gives me a directory list with date and time that I think I can use to achieve my goal. Here's a sample output:

`2016-12-01 18:06:40          0 sftp/
2016-12-01 20:35:39       1024 sftp/.ssh/.id_rsa.swp
2016-12-01 20:35:39       1679 sftp/.ssh/id_rsa
2016-12-01 20:35:39        405 sftp/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

What's the most effective way to iterate over all files but only copy those files more recent than the date indicated?

Here's the (incomplete) script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    key="$1"

    case $key in
        -m|--mtime)
            MTIME="$2"
            shift 2;;
        -s|--source)
            SRCDIR="$2"
            shift 2;;
        -d|--dest)
            DSTDIR="$2"
            shift 2;;
        *)
            #echo "Unknown argument: \"$key\""; exit 1;;
            break;;
    esac
done

if [ ! -d  $DSTDIR ]; then
    echo "the directory does not exist!";
    exit 1;
fi

GTDATE="$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -d "$MTIME days ago")"
#echo "Threshold: $GTDATE"

for f in $(aws s3 ls $SRCDIR --recursive | awk '{ ??? }'); do
    #aws s3 cp
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to know if the time stamp is local or UTC.
If local is America/Los_Angeles, date may interpret times incorrectly (note the difference 03 vs 11):

```
$ date  -d '20161201T18:06:40' +'%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S'
20161201T03:06:40

$ date -ud '20161201T18:06:40' +'%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S'
20161201T11:06:40
```

Using `-u` also avoids issues with DST and local changes.

In short life gets a lot easier if the date is recorded in a UTC format that the command `date` could read back, and has no spaces so `awk` or similar could parse it easily. For example:

```
$ date -ud '2016-12-01 18:06:40' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
2016-12-01T18:06:40
```

Both easier for the computer `date` and for the users reading it.
But you have a little different time stamp.

Assuming the files do not have names with newlines included.
The script after option processing should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SayError(){local a=$1; shift; printf '%s\n' "$0: $@" >&2; exit "$a"; }

[[ ! -d  $dstdir ]] && SayError 1 "The directory $dstdir does not exist!"
[[ ! -d  $srcdir ]] && SayError 2 "The source directory $srcdir doesn't exist"
[[ -z $mtime ]] && SayError 3 "The value of mtime has not been set."

gtdate="$(date -ud "$mtime days ago" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" )"
#echo "Threshold: $gtdate"

readarray -t files < <(aws s3 ls "$srcdir" --recursive)
limittime=$(date -ud "$gtdate" +"%s")

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    IFS=' ' read day time size name <<<"$f"
    filetime=$( date -ud "${day}T${time}" +"%s" )
    if [[ $filetime -gt $limittime ]]; then
        aws s3 cp "$srcdir/$name" "$destdir/"
    fi
done
```

Warning: Un-tested code, please review it carefully.

Comment: Is there a missing double-quote in `filetime=$(date -ud "${day}T${time} %s)`?

Answer (score 0):

one way is to sort the `s3 ls` results and the cutoff date together, and then cut off processing the s3 list when you hit the cutoff date:

```
cat <(echo "$GTDATE CUTOFF") <(aws s3 ls $SRCDIR --recursive) |
  sort -dr |
  awk '{if($3=="CUTOFF"){exit}print}' |
  xargs -I{} echo aws s3 cp "$SRCDIR/{}" "$DSTDIR/{}"
```

(i left in `echo` in the last line for you to test and see what commands would occur. remove the `echo` to actually to the `s3 cp` commands.)

(you could also use `s3 sync` instead of `cp` to avoid re-downloading files that are already up-to-date.)

Answer (score 0):

For search posterity, here's the draft of the final script (we are still reviewing; in practice, you'll want to comment out all but the last two `echo` calls):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# S3ToDirSync
#
# This script is a custom SFTP-S3 synchronizer utilizing the AWS CLI.
# 
# Usage: S3ToDirSync.sh -m 7 -d "/home/user" -b "user-data-files" -s "sftp"
# 
# Notes: 
#    The script is hardcoded to exclude syncing of any folder or file on a path containing "~archive"
#    See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#available-commands for AWS CLI documentation on commands
#
# Updated: 12/05/2016

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    key="$1"

    case $key in
        -m|--mtime)
            MTIME="$2" # nb of days (from now) to copy
            shift 2;;
        -b|--bucket)
            BUCKET="$2" # the S3 bucket, no trailing slashes
            shift 2;;
        -s|--source) # the S3 prefix/path, slashes at start and end of string will be added if not present
            SRCDIR="$2"
            shift 2;;
        -d|--dest) # the root destination folder
            DSTDIR="$2"
            shift 2;;
        *)
            #echo "Unknown argument: \"$key\""; exit 1;;
            break;;
    esac
done

# validations
if [ ! -d $DSTDIR ]; then
    echo "The destination directory does not exist.";
    exit 1;
fi
if [[ $DSTDIR != *"/" ]]; then
    DSTDIR=$DSTDIR\/
fi
echo "DSTDIR: $DSTDIR"

if [ -z $BUCKET ]; then
    echo "The bucket value has not been set.";
    exit 1;
fi

if [[ $BUCKET == *"/"* ]]; then
    echo "No slashes (/) in bucket arg.";
    exit 1;
fi
# add trailing slash
BUCKET=$BUCKET\/
echo "BUCKET: $BUCKET"

if [ -z $MTIME ]; then
    echo "The mtime value has not been set.";
    exit 1;
fi

# $SRCDIR may be empty, to copy everything in a bucket, but add a trailing slash if missing
if [ ! -z $SRCDIR ] && [[ $SRCDIR != *"/" ]]; then
    SRCDIR=$SRCDIR\/
fi
echo "SRCDIR: $SRCDIR"

SRCPATH=s3://$BUCKET$SRCDIR
echo "SRCPATH: $SRCPATH"

LIMITTIME=$(date -ud "$MTIME days ago" "+%s")
#echo "Threshold UTC Epoch: $LIMITTIME"

readarray -t files < <(aws s3 ls "$SRCPATH" --recursive) # TODO: ls will return up to a limit of 1000 rows, which could timeout or not be enough
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    IFS=' ' read day time size name <<<"$f"
    FILETIME=$(date -ud "${day}T${time}" "+%s")
    # if S3 file more recent than threshold AND if not in an "~archive" folder
    if [[ $FILETIME -gt $LIMITTIME ]] && [[ $name != *"~archive"* ]]; then
        name="${name/$SRCDIR/}" # truncate ls returned name by $SRCDIR, since S3 returns full path
        echo "$SRCPATH  $name"
        destpath=$DSTDIR$name
        echo "to $destpath"
        # if a directory (trailing slash), mkdir in destination if necessary
        if [[ $name == *"/" ]] && [ ! -d $destpath ]; then
            echo "mkdir -p $destpath"
            mkdir -p $destpath
        # else a file, use aws s3 sync to benefit from rsync-like checks
        else
            echo "aws s3 sync $SRCPATH$name $destpath"
            aws s3 sync $SRCPATH$name $destpath
            # NOTE: if a file was on S3 then deleted inside MTIME window, do we delete on SFTP server? If so, add --delete
        fi
    fi
done
```